# Finding Microsoft document about 'globe' contact in Outlook Address Book

Tags: microsoft-outlook, active-directory, contacts, address-book

In my Outlook Address Book, I see some contacts that have a globe icon next to it.  I cant find the contacts within Active Directory, Exchagne Server and wanted to know how to find and remove the contact.

I also searched on GG, and some of pepole said that they were custom recipients, i.e., their mailboxes were on some other system outside the Exchange organization...

I am not clear about that. So, I need to find Microsoft documents about this problem.
But, I dont receive any right results.

If you got the similar issues, please give me an advice!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These contacts with globe are actually Contacts. Those without globe are AD users. All that's simple =) You can easily delete these contacts using Exchange Management Console or Powershell.

Comment: Great! Your information is very helpful to me. But, i need a document to make sense with my team. Do you have it?

Comment: Sure! Take a look: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997138(v=exchg.141).aspx